# mvc 4 web api add custom response http header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-headers, asp.net-web-api

Can we add the extra http response header item example "Last Updated" beside the default response header?

example when I call (Request): 
localHost:12345/API/GetInfo 
with header:
Host: localHost:12345
......

then the api will reply the header with(Response):
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: XX
Content-Type: XXX
**Last-Update: The value and the value generate from the API function**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add header by using this code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Last-Update", value);
```

Comment: thanks bro. 
I Modified to HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Last-Update", value);

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. I fixed my answer. You're weclome)

Comment: Any way of doing it without using `System.Web.HttpContext`?

Comment: This is not encouraged, self hosting means `HttpContext.Current` is not available, so this will not always work.

Comment: I got another problem: when Browser perform next request. it does not not include the header "Last-Update" back to server. How to make browser return all headers from its prior response?

Comment: @TolaCh. response headers and request headers are totally different and you shouldn't put all response headers in request. But you can do it using js code on browser side.

Comment: This makes unit testing difficult - is it possible to set a header without using HttpContext.Current?

Comment: @HoberMellow ,how to handle this when we are calling webapi ?

Answer (score 9):

FYI there is an official HTTP Header that you can use to represent the DateTime a resource was last updated.

It is the 'Last-Modified' Header ([See section 14.29 on Section 14 page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) of the specification).

You add it to your response like this:

```
Response.Content.Headers.LastModified = yourResource.LastUpdatedDateTime;
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for custom response header(it can be other beside date), your answer was standard response header.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 5 just add

```
 Response.AppendHeader("header", "value");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution.
What I need to do is, response HTTP header in cookie format. That way, browser will always return it back to my web server.