# Unable to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on API response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, endpoint

I am currently converting a project from .Net Framework into .Net 5.

When I hit one of the endpoints within the new .Net 5 project I get the following exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Misused header name,
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Make sure request headers are used with
> HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and
> content headers with HttpContent objects.'

The endpoint looks like this, the exception is thrown on the line where I add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" onto the response content header.

```
 [HttpGet]
            [Route("api/Recommendations/GetRecommendations/{id}/{count}")]
            public HttpResponseMessage GetRecommendations(int id, int count)
            {

                var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                response.Content = new StringContent(_recommendationsAPIService.GetRecommendations(id, count));
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Referer, Authorization,Sec-Fetch-Mode,User-Agent");
                return response;
            }
```

How do I fix this exception?

I am not familiar with who originally wrote the project so is there any reason to add these headers onto the response anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `Content.Headers` property to add such headers. Check the documentation: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders?view=net-5.0)

> Represents the collection of Content Headers as defined in RFC 2616.

So it should be used for very specific headers.

Another Two things:

1st - You are adding the Header on the Content. The message is clear that you should add it to the response. Check here: [Add a custom response header in ApiController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017686/add-a-custom-response-header-in-apicontroller) for the way to add it to the response

```
 response.Headers.Add("X-Students-Total-Count", students.Count());
```

2nd - CORs is something that you need to apply globally! Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) on how to configure your api to do that.

TLDR;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                      "http://www.contoso.com");
                              });
        });

        // services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // Some code here

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```