# How to set header using IHttpActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, model-view-controller

i want to add token to header for webapi request.
how can i do this ?

this is my sample code

```
public IHttpActionResult Authenticate(Login data)
            {
                var Token = "fdsf123546fskjhf-gsuyuhsh";

                //here add these token to header

                return ?
            }
```

thank you.

Comment: This question is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487012/mvc-4-web-api-add-custom-response-http-header.

Answer (score 7):

1. You could use [ResponseMessageResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.responsemessageresult(v=vs.118).aspx) class for that:

   ```
   public IHttpActionResult Authenticate(Login data)
   {
       var Token = "fdsf123546fskjhf-gsuyuhsh";

       var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

       response.Headers.Add("Authentication", Token);

       return new ResponseMessageResult(response);
   }
   ```
2. Or create your own result class:

   ```
   public class HeaderActionResult : IHttpActionResult
   {
       private Tuple<string, string> header;

       public HeaderActionResult(Tuple<string, string> header) 
       {
           this.header = header;
       }

       public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
       {
           var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

           response.Headers.Add(header.Item1, header.Item2);

           return Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response);
       }
   }

   public IHttpActionResult Authenticate(Login data)
   {
       var Token = "fdsf123546fskjhf-gsuyuhsh";

       return new HeaderActionResult(Tuple.Create("Authentication", Token));
   }
   ```
3. Or add a header to any existing IHttpActionResult object using an extension method:

   ```
   public static class HttpActionResultExtensions
   {
       public static IHttpActionResult AddHeader(this IHttpActionResult actionResult, string name, string value)
       {
           return new HeaderActionResult(actionResult, name, value);
       }

       private class HeaderActionResult : IHttpActionResult
       {
           private readonly IHttpActionResult actionResult;

           private string name;

           private string value;

           public HeaderActionResult(IHttpActionResult actionResult, string name, string value)
           {
               this.actionResult = actionResult;

               this.name = name;

               this.value = value;
           }

           public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
           {
               HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await this.actionResult.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

               httpResponseMessage.Headers.Add(this.name, this.value);

               return httpResponseMessage;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks,  i am trying 1st solution  but i want to attach other data with that responce

Comment: @ShaikMatheen Then you could use the 3. solution for any existing IHttpActionResult object.

Comment: i have written above code and  its working fine , can please tell me is it right way to do?

Comment: @ShaikMatheen Yes, it's fine. You can also write it like `return Ok(Result).AddHeader("AccessToken", Token);` using the extension method from the 3. proposal.

Comment: i am getting below errorError if i use above code 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'AddHeader' and no extension method 'AddHeader' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ShaikMatheen The AddHeader method should be defined as an [extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) method (a static public method in a static class) - see the 3. proposal.

Answer (score 1):

This code working me

```
    public IHttpActionResult Authenticate(Login data)
            {
                        Status = "success";
                        Message = "You have been Authenticated successfully";
                        var Token = "fdsf123546fskjhf-gsuyuhsh";
                        var Result = new { Status = Status, Message = Message };

                        var Response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Result);
                        Response.Headers.Add("AccessToken", Token.AccessToken);

                        return ResponseMessage(Response);
            }
```